# Process multiple HDFS paths in parallel

Tags: json, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, filesystems

I have a file which contains many hdfs paths. each HDFS path contains some JSON files. I want to process all those json files which are updated in last 24 hours.
For now I am reading the file which contains the paths and processing all the paths sequentially. But its taking alot of time.

After processing I also need to add it to hive table.So Hivecontext might also come in picture while processing it parallely.
So the question is how can I process them parallel.

I tried:

- reading file which contains paths using sc.textfile and use foreach
     in which I faced "filesystem object is not serialized error"
  So I made a list of all recently updated files in a list (I did it sequencially) and tried to process that list in parallel(by calling sc.parallelize and foreach).But then I got nullpointerexception.

Now I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @user8371915 No its not. That question talks about group by.

Comment: Are all files processed the same way?

Comment: @ayplam yes. processing logic is same for all files

Comment: problem I am facing is I am not able to access HiveContext/sqlContext in foreach logic